# Custom Workflow Activity vs Web Services in SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, web-services, workflow-activity, best-practices

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 workflow project which needs some business logic. In SharePoint 2013, workflows are declarative. So to write a custom code, its advised to create a web service and consume it in the workflow. However, i have also tried using a custom activity to write custom code and its working correctly. **My query- which is the preferred method ? Is it a best practice to use custom activity to write business logic?**

Comment: @SlavenSemper Thanks for the response. Could you please post this as an answer so that i can mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done both and from my experience things are a lot easier when you use web services. You don't have to kill *vssphost5.exe* process all the time if you're using web services. From architecture side of things if custom activity is something that will be reused in workflows then I would definitely use custom activities. For all other scenarios I prefer web services.